# iOS: Is there a way to reload a UIWebView from tabBar when the tabBar item is already selected?

Tags: uiwebview, ios6, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

This might sound silly but i have a tab bar in my app delegate and my view controllers are loading when user taps a tab. In my view controller i have a UIwebview that loads a simple website. Instead of having to create a home button to reload the web view, i was looking to see if i can use the already selected tab bar item to reload the website. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

since you have tabbar delegate, set reload function at

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
    //reload webview
}
```